# Android Inflater crashes

Tags: android, eclipse, android-inflate

I am trying to build an android app. My idea is to create a glossary-app, and It has been up and running, but when I tried to add a Spinner, it crashed. Now I have removed the Spinner, but the app still crashes.

```
05-21 10:51:29.970: E/AndroidRuntime(22736): android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler onLanguageButtonClick in class se.inceptive.irebglossary.MainActivity
05-21 10:51:29.970: E/AndroidRuntime(22736):    at se.inceptive.irebglossary.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:58)
```

And this is presented at line 58:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Any help on this is very appreciated

*MainActivity.java*

```
package se.inceptive.irebglossary;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
import se.inceptive.irebglossary.DisplayDescription;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
//    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private ListView termsListView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    termsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.termsListView);



 // Initialize the terms array
    Term [] items = {
            new Term(1, "Acceptance", "The process of assessing whether a system satisfies all its requirements", false, "Acceptans", ""),
            new Term(2, "Acceptance test", "A test that assesses whether a system satisfies all its requirements", false, "Acceptans test", ""),
            new Term(3, "Activity diagram", "A diagram type in UML which models the flow of actions in a system or in a component including data flows and areas of responsibility where necessary", false, "Aktivitets diagram", ""),
            new Term(4, "Actor", "1. Generally in RE: A person, a system or a technical device in the context of a system that interacts with the system.2. Especially in goal-oriented RE: a person, a system or a technical device that may act and process information in order to achieve some goals", false, "Aktör", ""),
    };
    ArrayAdapter<Term> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Term>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    termsListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    termsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DisplayDescription.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, item);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: can you show your R.menu.main xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have specified the onClick handler for one of your menu items (in the XML) to be `onLanguageButtonClick`, but you have not provided the implementation for the `onLanguageButtonClick` in your activity code.

Comment: Thanks alot. I had indeed an onClick there. Helped by removing it for now.